# Javascript/JQuery How to get the live/actual color of an element after it has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a table with many rows, each with a unique ID. When a user clicks on a row it changes the colour of the row to act like its been selected. The original row colour is "#EBEBEB"

```
document.getElementById("selector" + iSelected).style.backgroundColor = '#F1F7DB';
```

When the javascript successfully changes the background colour, how do I then retrieve the value of its new colour using javascript,

```
alert(document.getElementById('selector' + iSelected).style.backgroundColor);
```

this displays its original value dispite it now being a different colour.

Comment: I think it returns the color of a different row. Post your html. And the relevant script

Comment: Does the {{"selector" + iSelected}} equal {{'data-row' + iSelected}}?

Comment: Yes sorry "data-row" and "selector" are one and the same

Comment: Has the value of `iSelected` changed?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("bar").style.background="rgb(69,69,69)";
alert(document.getElementById("bar").style.background);

})
```

```css
#bar{width:100px;
height:100px;
background:pink;}
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery implementation of changing a color and displaying the color.  Unfortunately, due to how colors are done in CSS you won't be able to get "gray" back.  But, you could do an associated array with all the different pre-defined colors and look it up (comment if you want me to look into that).

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $("#bar").css("background","gray"); //changes the color to gray
    alert($("#bar").css("background-color")); //makes a popup that displays the color
});
```